# How to change marker color with a different marker icon

Tags: java, android-studio, maps, google-maps-markers

At the moment marker icons are in default shape and color is a variable (different colors for different locations) as in below code.

```
 markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(obj.getColor()));
```

But what I was trying is to change the shape by keeping the color assignment as described in the custom method that I have defined (obj.getColor()).

I have tried using below (shape changed) ;

```
markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pushpin))
```

Though the shape changed, all the icons are red, which is not the requirement. But there is no option like in default marker to change the color.

Any guide on this please to change the colors as well as changing the shape of the marker?

Comment: If you're just using that one line with [fromResource](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/BitmapDescriptorFactory.html) to draw all markers, it's equivalent to using 1 resource bitmap image for all markers. That explains all icons being the same shape and color. You can try to have different colored `pushpin` images in your resources folder and cycle through those as you create markers.

Comment: well...thank you for the suggestion, but seems like this may not work for my requirement when there are many locations with different color requirements.